# Start Firebug when radio button is clicked

Tags: debugging, firebug

I have a complicated mess of code (built by a team of 7 over the course of several years) that incorporates multiple libraries - jQuery and angularjs, specifically.

I know that the value of a variable changes when I click a certain radio button, but I have no idea what is running when that happens to cause the variable to change. I've tried `console.log` in every place I can think of, but am somehow still missing the action that's changing the variable.

I know how to debug with Firebug if I know where to place my breakpoint, but in this case, I don't. Is there any way to tell Firebug to start debugging at the line that executes immediately after the radio button is clicked? In other words, when I click the radio button, open Firebug's [*Script* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel) to the first line in order of execution, wherever that line may be.

Answer (score 1):

If you have chrome you can right click on the checkbox -> inspect element -> event listeners

Comment: It doesn't show angular handlers - i.e. `ng-click`. Which doesn't matter anyway, because there is no `ng-click` on the element. It has to be a watcher somewhere, but there's nothing in the codebase that points to the element id.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to tell Firebug to start debugging at the line that
>   executes immediately after the radio button is clicked?

Yes, this feature is called [Break On Next](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel#Break_On_Next).

Note that Firebug has much more features to debug your scripts besides setting breakpoints within the Script panel. These features are described in the ['Script Debugging' page inside the Firebug wiki](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Debugging).

Furthermore the [*Watch* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Watch_Side_Panel) allows you to inspect the variable to see, at which step it is changed.

Comment: I'm aware of those options, thanks. Some of them get flaky when dealing with variables that are not straight JS (i.e. an angular variable is defined as $scope.varName.)

Comment: This results in a "$scope not defined" error when trying to use it in the Watch panel.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some example code or a URL, so your problem can actually be reproduced.